# How can i get image type from this kind of link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is about how can i get image type from this kind of link?

> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71b0d516013802a2d67aeb7c2e77ed32?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

For example, in HTML like this:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71b0d516013802a2d67aeb7c2e77ed32?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="-avatar js-avatar-me">
```

For link like this `http://localhost/assets/images/main.jpg` i tried

```
var imgType = url.split('.').pop();
```

For a URL like this `something.jpg?name=blah` or `something.jpg#blah` I have used:

```
url.split('.').pop().split(/\#|\?/)[0];
```

to get the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the content is dynamically generated and has no file extension, then you cannot dissect the URL using `split()`. Even then, relying on the filename is not accurate as you can simply rename any file to `.jpg`. It could still be a `application/text` file, or any other MIME type.

Instead, you can make an AJAX request to the location of the image and retrieve the `content-type` header from the response, like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71b0d516013802a2d67aeb7c2e77ed32?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1',
  success: function(r, s, x){ 
    var type = x.getResponseHeader("content-type");
    console.log(type); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can i do the same with pure javascript?? @Rory McCrossan